# Running a python2.7 function from a python3 script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, boto

So I'm trying to use [boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but I find there's only a Python2 version of it and I'm using Python3 (I can't change this). So, I'm wondering if there's any way to run python2 functions from within python3.

Basically I have a module that has a number of functions that only work in Python2. Is there someway I can call one of those functions from within a python3 script? Basically

```
# Python 3 script
def function():
    arg1 = blah
    arg2 = blah2
    fun2(arg1, arg2)
```

And the other one

```
# Python 2 script
def fun2(arg1, arg2):
    # Do stuff
```

I tried the 2to3 script, had to manually edit some paths but found that other things still weren't working and I didn't want to go through the trouble of finding all the conversion issues

Comment: You might want to checkout the py3kport branch of boto.  It should be compatible with Python 3 and a number of people have been using it successfully although it is not officially supported.  Also, there is botocore and awscli which provide similar capabilities but are compatible with both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: I've tried installing the py3kport and keep getting errors. I can't even connect to a bucket using the same code